# Can't use modules from Python 3.4

Tags: python, module

I'm pretty frustrated after trying a lot of different solutions, with no success.
I'm trying to use statistics module from Python 3.4, and keep getting:

```
ImportError: No module named statistics
```

I tried fixing it with PYTHONPATH, and it works, but than it shows an error of another part of the code (code that worked well in the past):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 182
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What can I do?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you are using vs 3.4? what does `import sys ; print(sys.version)` result in?  If you manually put the 3.4 library on the path and you are using vs2 then it is invalid syntax for vs2

Comment: Are you sure you tried to import `statistics` from Python3.4 and not Python 2.x ?

Comment: i get version 2.7.6.
ok, thats probably the problem... my OS is ubuntu 14.04 so python 3.4 is installed, so how do i fix this? thank you very much!

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4 is called 'python3'.

Comment: ok, but still, what do i need to do?

Comment: guys, help please?

Comment: (1) Did you install python2 and python3 through the packet manager (apt, aptitude, synaptic), or manually? (2) How do you run your python code? From the commandline (interactive), from a python file, from an IDE? If interactive, did you type `python` or `python3`? If running a file, does it have the right [shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/1292641)? If an IDE, which one?

Comment: I'm sorry Python gives you trouble. But it seems this problem is easy to fix. We just need a little more information than the error message. It really looks like you just started the wrong python interpreter (`python` instead of `python3`), or the script file is missing the correct shebang line, or the PATH is bad.